# Why doesn't it show me the value of a variable when I cast the object containing it?

Tags: java, casting

I am currently trying to compare two GolfCard objects, and I have a runner class that calls the method `.equals`, which I have overridden in my GolfCard class. It works perfectly fine, but when I debug it just to see what's going on, it shows me the value of face of the non casted GolfCard object, but it doesn't show me the value of face of the casted GolfCard object.

```
if (this.face != ((GolfCard)obj).face)
```

When I highlight over face of the non casted object, it says:

```
"face(GolfCard) = 11;"
```

But when I highlight over face of the casted object, it says:

```
"int GolfGame.GolfCard.face"
```

Why does it show me the value of the variable of the non-casted object, but not of the variable of the casted object?

Comment: I am guessing your language is Java, but it worth mention it in the question...

Comment: Please, add more tags to your question, so we'd know what language is that and/or framework if you're using one, and other things worth tagging.

Comment: just wondering, what's the point of adding details about equality check? Question wouldn't be simple if you just said value not showing in casted object but showing in non casted object only during debugging?

Comment: Which debugger?

Answer (score 1):

Because there is no casted object in your example.

`((GolfCard)obj).face` is an expression that contains a temporary cast, however you don't have any local variable of type `GolfCard` that you assign the cast to.

Your debugger does not cast `obj` when you hover over `face`, and thus it won't be able to show you a value, as there is no value at that point in time. The value only exists when the entire expression `((GolfCard)obj).face` is evaluated.

To see the value in your debugger, you can add the entire expression `((GolfCard)obj).face` explicitly to a list of watched expressions.

In Eclipse you have a window called "Expressions" that is default visible in the debugger perspective. If you add `((GolfCard)obj).face` there, it will show you the value.

The reason for this is mostly performance and stability. If your compiler did evaluate every cast or otherwise complex expression when you hover over it with your mouse, it would have to handle potential ClassCastExceptions and run possibly complex code all the time, even if you don't need or want it. The explicit expressions allow you to tell it when you do want it to perform more complex tasks to evaluate a value during debugging.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have this construct:

```
class A {
    int face = 11;
}

class B extends A {
    int face = 42;
}
```

That is: in class B there is a new field `face` that hides a field `face` in class A.

Some compilers issue a warning "field hides a field of an ancestor class."

That construct is quite misleading and maybe just intends to do:

```
class B extends A {
    B() {
        face = 42; // A.face
    }
}
```

Otherwise it would be best to rename `face` in `B`.

(In java fields are not *overriding* but add to the data.)